# https://www not redirecting to my domain when everything else

Tags: apache, https, security-certificate, namecheap

I'm using namecheap, letsencrypt and apache. I registered with letsencrypt the domain and www, but it's not even getting to the "your connection is unsecure" page.

namecheap has an A record to my ip address for my server, as well as a 'URL redirect' from www to non-www

Apache has nothing special other than: SSLRequireSSL which seems to redirect all my links to SSL

**Works**

- https://
- http://
- www.
- http://www
- ip
- http://ip
- https://ip

**Does not work**

- https://www

I've tried using a CNAME www record and a URL Redirect www record, and neither seem to fix my problem.

Another note is when force refreshing the page for https://www my browser says "Unable to connect".

Any ideas?

Comment: Please use just one account (the same as you asked this question with) so that you can receive comment notifications, accept answers, build reputation, etc... You can request for accounts to be merged following [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 2):

The letsencrypt changed default-ssl.conf -> DocumentRoot was pointing at the default /var/www/html which was why I was getting a 403. Changed it to the correct path and now https://www redirects to non-www

Comment: I am glad you found an answer and shared it with us. Congratulations! Cheers!!